# Multi-criteria lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want the code value in column B if the handset matches and the date is between the date from and the date to.
[image]

How the results should look:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to write some VBA code for your lookup ? It would do this: run through the rows of your destination tables, for each row run through the source table, compare if source and destination values match, and if there is a match copy the code from source table to dest table.

Comment: I will probably have to write a VBA function for this. I just thought someone may have already done this so it would be useful to see their solution.

Comment: I'm sure if you search thoroughly, you can find something close to what you need and adapt it with only a few tweeks. Anyway, you could take the logic from my previous comment, it will guide you on your code tryouts. Don't hesitate to come back with code samples once you have something written and tested :)

Comment: You should have two cells for the start and end date, one cell for the handset being sought, and one column for the codes (results). Then when you change the dates or the handset, the column should be filled with the matches. Your second image is showing something different. Could you clarify what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Since you problem involve `Date Range`, therefore `Vlookup & Index match` is not possible to solve, I will use `If + AND` formula to solve your problem:

```
=IF(AND(E9>$G$3,E9<$H$3,F9=$E$3),$F$3,
     IF(AND(E9>$G$4,E9<$H$4,F9=$E$4),$F$4,
       IF(AND(E9>$G$5,E9<$H$5,F9=$E$5),$F$5,
         IF(AND(E9>$G$6,E9<$H$6,F9=$E$6),$F$6,""))))
```

[image]

Comment: Note: this kind of Excel formula is OK if you only have a few cells, but is not sustainable for bigger datatables.

Comment: Yes unfortunately my table is much larger, this is just a snippit of the data.

Comment: Ya, if you need VBA then you have to study and test on your own, if you have no idea in VBA, even 20 `if statement` you have to do so, nothing come for free :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add a column, one possible solution without using VBA would be to use a combination of SUMIFS and XLOOKUP formulas.

In column E, add a unique identification number (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.).  You could reference the row number or manually fill down the numbers or whatever.  It wouldn't matter as long as the values are unique and all numbers (no text).

Then, use a SUMIFS formula to sum Column E if (1) the handset number matches, (2) the date is greater than or equal to the start date, and (3) the date is less than or equal to the finish date.  As long as there are no overlaps in the date ranges for each handset, this will return the unique ID number.  Depending on the dataset, you might have to play with the less/greater than or equal to vs just less/greater than.

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,I2,C:C,"<="&H2,D:D,">="&H2)
```

Then, use the XLOOKUP to return the code based on the unique ID.  In this example, I combined the SUMIFS and XLOOKUP in one formula, but you could also do it in two columns to provide better visibility.

```
=XLOOKUP(SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,I2,C:C,"<="&H2,D:D,">="&H2),E:E,B:B,"NOT FOUND",0,1)
```

Here's an example.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxRU3.png)